# filter and map on object of arrays based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, filter

Hi I have an array `group` based on which I'm creating an array of categories for a certain language. I would like to produce the same array but only using filter and map methods.

```
  var group = [
    {
      nodes: [
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'someCategory DE',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'de',
          },
        },
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'HTML&CSS DE',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'de',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      nodes: [
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'react',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'en',
          },
        },
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'HTML&CSS',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'en',
          },
        },
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'javascript',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'en',
          },
        },
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'someCategory',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'en',
          },
        },
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'HTML&CSS',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'en',
          },
        },
        {
          frontmatter: {
            category: 'react',
          },
          fields: {
            locale: 'en',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

My working code without using filter and map.

```
const locale = 'de'
const arr = []

group.forEach(el => {
    el.nodes.forEach(e => {
      if (e.fields.locale == locale) {
        arr.push(e.frontmatter.category)
      }
    })
  })
```

expected result for example for *'en'* language

```
arr = ["react", "HTML&CSS", "javascript", "someCategory", "HTML&CSS", "react"]
```

thank you

Comment: do you have only one language in the inner arrays? please add the wanted result.

Comment: Thank you @NinaScholz. I added expected result. Yes, there will be only one language for 'locale'

Comment: sorry i mean is only one language in each  nodes or could be more than one?

Comment: only one, the nodes are grouped by language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very compact completely declarative method that returns an unique list of categories matching the input locale.

```js
const group = [{ nodes: [{ frontmatter: { category: 'someCategory' }, fields: { locale: 'de' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'de' } }] }, { nodes: [{ frontmatter: { category: 'react' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'javascript' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'someCategory' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'react' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }] }];

// Function:

const getCategoriesByLocale = locale => [...new Set(
  group
    .flatMap(g => g.nodes.filter(n => n.fields.locale == locale))
    .map(n => n.frontmatter.category)
)];

// Usage:

console.log(getCategoriesByLocale("en"));
console.log(getCategoriesByLocale("de"));
```

If uniqueness is actually not what you want, you can remove the `Set` wrapper for an even shorter function:

```
const getCategoriesByLocale = locale => 
  group
    .flatMap(g => g.nodes.filter(n => n.fields.locale == locale))
    .map(n => n.frontmatter.category);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const 
  group = [{ nodes: [{ frontmatter: { category: 'someCategory' }, fields: { locale: 'de' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'de' } }] }, { nodes: [{ frontmatter: { category: 'react' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'javascript' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'someCategory' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'react' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }] }],
  locale = 'de';

let arr = [];
  
group.forEach((el) => {
  arr = arr.concat(el.nodes.filter((e) => {
    return e.fields.locale == locale;
  }).map((e) => {
    return e.frontmatter.category;
  }));
});

// or

arr = [];

group.forEach((el) => {
  let nodesWithDesiredLocale = el.nodes.filter((e) => {
    return e.fields.locale == locale;
  })
  
  let desiredCategories = nodesWithDesiredLocale.map((e) => {
    return e.frontmatter.category;
  });
  
  arr = arr.concat(desiredCategories);
});
  
console.log(arr, 'using filter and map');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter and map the wanted property.

```js
const
    group = [{ nodes: [{ frontmatter: { category: 'someCategory' }, fields: { locale: 'de' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'de' } }] }, { nodes: [{ frontmatter: { category: 'react' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'javascript' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'someCategory' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'HTML&CSS' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }, { frontmatter: { category: 'react' }, fields: { locale: 'en' } }] }],
    locale = 'de',
    result = group
        .filter(({ nodes: [{ fields }] }) => fields.locale === locale)
        .flatMap(({ nodes }) => nodes.map(({ frontmatter: { category } }) => category));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Incredible use of JavaScript.

Comment: What about ````group.filter(({ nodes: [{ fields }]}) => fields.locale == locale).map(({ nodes: [{ frontmatter }]}) => frontmatter.category)````